# Ruby on Rails DRY Best Practice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

I'm learned RoR programming through Mickael Hartl's tutorial, which I really enjoyed.

Now I'm developing an application with 8 types of objects.

For each object, I need to assign a status, coming from a statuses table, and to assign current user's name.

In each controller, in private section, I wrote a statuses_list function and a current_user_name, which make these data available to select fields in the forms respectively.

This does not sound DRY-like that much.
Would it be relevant and secure to write such functions as helpers so the data are available anywhere in my application ?

Thanks for your advice,

Best regards,

Frédéric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, thanks to all the answers collected, here is how I did :

Defined a `set_statuses_list` method in a `ParametersHelper`

Added `include ParamtersHelper` to the `ApplicationController`

Added `before_action :set_statuses_list` in each of my 8 objects controllers

It feels like a good balance, and I'll be happy to get comments about it.
Note that the `current_user` method was indeed already available through the `SessionsHelper`.

Thanks for your help,

Best regards,

Frédéric

Answer (score 1):

Move those methods to their home classes. `Status.list()` and `User.current_user()`. That's generally how people solve the problem "everyone needs a `current_user`, but nobody wants a `$current_user` global variable.

Then assign the `current_user` very early in your `before_filter`s, when the authentication system identifies the user. And read /Confident Ruby/, by Avdi Grimm, for a very good write-up on how and why to create a `Guest` user, for `current_user` to return if nobody is logged in: http://devblog.avdi.org/2013/08/26/confident-ruby-is-finished/

Answer (score 1):

Putting the methods in a helper file is the best way to make them available in your views, but if you **also** want to make these methods available in your controllers, then put these as methods in `ApplicationController` and at the top specify:

`helper_method: :statuses_list, :current_user_name`

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would recomment using inheritance to give some controller some same methods.

Create a SuperClass that extends ApplicationController like:

```
class SuperController < ApplicationController
    [...]
end
```

and subclass it

```
class MyControllerClass < SuperController
    [...]
end
```

Put the repetitive stuff in the SuperController - et voila ! MyControllerClass inherits methods SuperController so you dont need to repeat them.

Answer (score 0):

To make your code accessible throughout your application, you have to mention it in `helpers`. This is ofcourse a `DRY` principle and would help you to reduce the same line of code again and again..

Comment: Putting code in `app/helpers` is not the only way to share code across a Rails application. Rails is just Ruby, so you can have any Ruby object anywhere and simply `require` that file where you need to use it in order to share it.

Comment: instead of creating a new ruby file and making its object and sharing it across, why not use rails inbuilt feature of `helpers`

Comment: Methods in helpers get added to the global namespace and can cause confusing method lookup chain problems. Encapsulation and single responsibility principle are also good object oriented design patterns that should be balanced with having functionality available everywhere. It depends a lot on what you are doing exactly, but in my experience, I find a plain old Ruby object to be a much better design decision than creating a method in a helper 99% of the time..

Comment: `It depends a lot on what you are doing exactly`. I though agree with this `Methods in helpers get added to the global namespace and can cause confusing method lookup chain problems`